Turing machines using finitely many tape cells
Define a language:
$$L=\left\{ \langle M\rangle \ \vert \ \exists x\in\Sigma^*: \text{The run of $M$ on $x$ visits only finitely many tape cells} \right\}$$
I think that this language is recognizable and not decidable, but I am not sure how to prove it. How does simulation work in the sense of number of cells?

Which part(s) are you unsure about proving?  Recognizability, undecidability, both?

I think that $L\in\text{RE}$ by a TM that given $M$, for all $i$, run $M$ on $w_1,\dots,w_i$ for $i$ steps. If $M$ halts or visits the same configuration twice - accept. What do you think?

@David that works

Thanks! and how can I show that $L\notin R$? I want to define a reduction $\text{HP}\le L$, but how can I make sure that if M does not halt on x, the run of the output TM on all words will need infinitely many cells?

As you mention in the comments, a recognizer for this language can run $M$ gradually for more and more steps on more and more inputs until it either halts or we can detect a repeat configuration.
To show it is not decidable we can reduce from the halting problem as you suggest. The difficulty you mention can be avoided by hard-coding the input. Given a machine $M$ and an input $x,$ compute a description of a machine $M'$ such that on any input, we just run $M$ on $x$. Pass the description into the oracle and if it says $M'\notin L,$ then reject. If it says $M'\in L$ then we can safely run $M$ on $x$ to see whether it halts or has a repeat configuration and accept or reject accordingly.
